# What's a good starting value for a min (or max) variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

Let's say I'm keeping track of the maximum value encountered so far as I traverse a list or a stream of integers. The traditional variable initialization looks like this:

```
maxNum = <min-possible-value>

for num in listOfNums:
    maxNum = max(maxNum, num)
```

Given that `sys.maxint` isn't a thing in Python3 and practically there isn't a limit to how large (or small) an `int` can be, what should I initialize maxNum to? or what are better alternative ways to do this?

(Note: `sys.maxsize` isn't quite the same as `sys.maxint` and yes `int` can hold a value larger than `sys.maxsize`)

Is `math.inf` viable? Note that this value is a float rather than an int

Comment: use `float('inf')` or `float('-inf')` why does it matter if it is a float? They are defined to do exactly what you need, compare as less than or greater than any other number

Comment: Or, you can just use the first int in the stream/list, which works (although can make the code a little uglier)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `float('inf')` and `float('-inf')` to generate values that will always evaulate as greater than or less than typical numbers respectively.

Comment: yes, the only vlues that will trip this up are `float('nan')` and the infinities themselves, so in that sense, it is very appropriate to use if you have only `int`s

Answer (score 3):

Use the first element of the list.

```
maxNum = listOfNums[0]

for num in listOfNums:
    maxNum = max(maxNum, num)
```

The only problem would be if `listOfNums` is empty. If this is a possibility, you should just check for it before this code (you need to do that anyway, so you can assign `maxNum` appropriately in this case).

```
if listOfNums:
    maxNum = listOfNums[0]
    for num in listOfNums:
        maxNum = max(maxNum, num)
else:
    maxNum = None
```

Comment: What if it is a part of recursion? For example for finding min number recursively, what should be done?

Comment: A common way is to split it into a regular 1-argument wrapper and 2-argument recursive function. The wrapper calls `recursive_min(l[0], l[1:])`

Answer (score 3):

The thing you're looking for is called the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) for the maximum function. There are different identity elements for different functions.

In case of the maximum function, the value is -∞ and I would expect it in a math context, so:

```
import math
maximum_identity_element = -math.inf
```

Comment: Infinity and identity are completely different things, and not seeing how identity is related to the question

Comment: @OneCricketeer it's just math-y terminology, for a given binary relation, F on a set S, an element i such that F(x, i) = x for all x is called an identity element

Comment: Right, I'm (roughly) familiar with set theory. Seemed to be tangential to the actual question, though

Comment: @OneCricketeer: for me it isn't tangential. People know to choose MAXINT or whatever constant, but they don't know why. If OP knew he's not looking for MAXINT, but Identity = -Infinity instead, he probably needn't be asking.

Comment: I mean, OP did say "Is math.inf viable?", so the answer could have just been "yes", IMO. Anyways, its good context for learning purposes

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this one element at a time?  You can simply use

```
maxnum = max(ListOfNums)
```

Failing that, use the appropriate `-inf` value for your base type.